# Write regular expression for repeated consecutive characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string, `var str = "abcc"`, if `var regExp = /(.)\1+/`, then it successfully identify "cc" by running `"abcc".match(regExp);`, but why `/.\1+/` not works since it also means more than one copies of the previous character? 
Please provide some insight?

Comment: https://regexper.com run them through this

Comment: Cool! I just tested the regular expression on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.)` denotes a **capture group** that is later referred to using `\1`, so basically you say "find multiple occurrences of capture group 1".

Your second example won't work because there is no capture group involved.

Comment: I want to know why I have to use 'capture group' in this case to make it work. Does '/.\1+/' not indicate the repeated consecutive characters? I don't understand it.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks again.

Comment: Without a capture group, `\1` is meaningless. If removed and left with `/.+/` (or even `/(.)+/`, this would simply mean "match one or more of any character" and would match any string longer than zero characters.